# Current flows which way?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, electric-circuits

[Current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) flows through a resistor (with no direction since it is not a vector/can flow from any potential)?

I thinks it is with no direction since it is not a vector. Is that right?

Comment: Note that the [current density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density) is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

A current is like the flow of a fluid, so it's a [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field). We tend to think of resistors as one dimensional when we draw circuit diagrams, but of course they aren't.

Comment: Should we be careful with the use of **current** vs **current density**? The current density is a **vector field** defined proportional to the electric field, whereas the current is defined as the integral of the component of the current density through some particular cross-sectional area.

Comment: @JohnRennie Isn't current a scalar, though? It doesn't follow the Vector Law of Addition, neither can you divide it into components like vectors.

Comment: @mikhailcazi How does it not follow vector addition? Show me. See my solution.

Comment: @Will Well if you take wires arranged in a closed polygon, vector  sum says the resultant current should be zero, but that's not true - a circuit is a closed polygon. And current _does_ flow.

Comment: @mikhailcazi Read my solution below. You can't think of currents that way. The current is described with respect to a prescribed area. In the case of a wire this is the cross-sectional area. So putting the wires in a closed polygon isn't adding currents.

Comment: @Will But that's just it, right? Putting wires together is NOT adding currents. If it was a vector, we'd be able to add it - like force. And if we divide a wire into two, the current through each path will depend on the resistances of each path; not the angle between them - as is the case with vectors.

Comment: @mikhailcazi did you read my solution? In my solution I have explained that it is a 1-D vector, which is a scalar. Vector addition is scalar addition in 1-D. John was mistakingly thinking of **current density** above. Yes current is not a 3-D vector field, it is a 1-D vector (a scalar).

Comment: @Will Yes I did. You derived current from Ohm's Law $J = \sigma E$, right? And since 1D vector is equal to a scalar anyway, and John was talking about $J$, this argument seems to be pointless. :P :D P.S. Halliday-Resnick-Krane's PHYSICS states that it doesn't follow the laws for Vector Addition.

Comment: My point was that you need to be careful about what space your vector lives in. Agreed that this is pointless! End of pointless discussion. :P

Answer (score 1):

I feel really bad for the OP getting these downvotes. The question (if worded better) is a really good question. There is obviously a lot of confusion over this - given the range of solutions posted. I think the main confusion comes from two places: (1) using **current density** in place of **current** (whether consciously or not), (2) Not realizing that a **1-D vector** is a **scalar**.

---

**Current density:**

For simplicity, assume we have a conductor with a constant conductance, $\sigma$. Also for simplicity, let's assume that the electric field is time-independent, but could vary in space. The **electric field**, $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$, is a **vector field**, that is, at each point in space, we associate a vector space. The relationship between the electric field and the **current density** in this simplified model is
$$\vec{J}(\vec{x}) = \sigma~\vec{E}(\vec{x})$$
From this equation, we see that $\vec{J}(\vec{x})$, the **current density**, is also a **vector field**.

---

**Current:**

The **current** is defined with reference to some **area** as
$$I_A = \int_A \vec{J}(\vec{x})\cdot d\vec{A}$$
In circuits, the area we care about is the cross-sectional area of the wire. With a DC source  the electric field is constant throughout the wire (if AC, still constant spatially but has time dependence), that is $\vec{E}(\vec{x}) = E_0~\hat{z}$ (assuming the wire is along the $z$-axis). This means that the **current density** is $$\vec{J} = \sigma~E_0~\hat{z}$$ and so the **current** is (area of interest is the cross-section of the wire, with $d\vec{A} = dA\hat{z}$)
$$I = \int dA~\sigma E_0~\hat{z}\cdot\hat{z} = A\sigma ~ E_0$$
In this idealized situation, we see that $I$ can be treated as a 1-D **vector**, so far as the vector space axioms are concerned. We also note that a 1-D vector **is a scalar!** *Note that I am not saying scalar* **field** *or vector* **field**.

---

**Let's see what happens when we aren't confined to a wire and have spatial varying electric fields.**

Take some area through a region in a conductor (with constant $\sigma$ as before) where the electric field has spatial dependence $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$. The current associated with this electric field and area is
$$I_A = \sigma\int_A \vec{E}(\vec{x})\cdot d\vec{A}$$
With a little thought, one can see that this doesn't change the argument in our wire case. The current defined this way still produces a 1-D vector, whose direction indicates which way the total flow of *positive* charges (by convention) is flowing, through the prescribed surface. And again, a 1-D vector **IS** a scalar.

---

Note: in this situation, adding currents is *physically* identical to adding electric fields (as $\sigma$ is assumed constant).

Answer (score 0):

Electric current has a direction and that is the direction in which positive charge flows.

In circuit theory, electric current enters the positive terminal of a resistor and exits the negative terminal.

If electric current did not have a direction, how would we determine the polarity of a [magnetic dipole due to a current loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Current_loop_definition)?